# Problem with teleop

Tags: navigation, roslaunch, husky, joystick, teleop

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

My teleop didnt work properly in my electric installation. I got the command velocity info that I passed to husky A200. But the problem was, husky didnt move a bit. So I tried to replace the below mentioned three packages with another set of same packages in opt/ros/electric/stacks:-

> clearpath_common

> clearpath_husky

> clearpath_kinect

I also rosmaked all of them. It all went error free. But, when I tried to run:-

> roslaunch husky_teleop teleop.launch

It gave me this error :-

> ERROR: cannot launch node of type [clearpath_teleop/teleop.py]: Cannot locate node of type [teleop.py] in package [clearpath_teleop]

But the node is present, when I checked the location. I also tried to replace the new ones with my old packages. But still the same error persisted.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42877/problem-with-teleop/) by [Arjun PE](https://answers.ros.org/users/2019/arjun-pe/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2012-09-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are you sure that `clearpath_teleop` is in your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH? Try with `roscd clearpath_teleop`.

Also, I don't believe this will solve the problem you had according to [your previous question](http://answers.ros.org/question/42643/unable-to-do-teleop/). Did you try fixing what I assume to be a networking problem? Otherwise, this node won't work either.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-09-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2